# uWSGI to serve flask app and non-app processes alongside each other

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing, uwsgi

There is `--callable app` option for serving flask with uWSGI. But what is my strategy, if I have additional process(es) for the rest of my architecture?

Say, I have the following oversimplified application:

```
from flask import Flask
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import time


app = Flask(__name__)
m = Manager()
ns = m.Namespace()
ns.x = 0

@app.route('/')
def index():
    x = ns.x
    return "Current number is {}".format(x)


class AddP(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        Process.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        while True:
            ns.x += 1
            time.sleep(5)

class AppP(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        Process.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        app.run(debug=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = AddP()
    p2 = AppP()
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p1.terminate()
    p2.terminate()
```

I obviously cannot call just `app` here.

Comment: You should run them separately. Don't start new processes in an WSGI app.

Comment: And how do I achieve that, Klaus?